# Dice rolling sum and 7-card probability questions

Tags: probability

> 1. We are playing with fair fifty-sided dice numbered 1–50. Suppose we roll three of them. What is the probability that the sum of the numbers on the dice is 37?
> 2. What is the probability that a seven-card poker hand contains a seven-card straight?

For the first question, I am not sure of an easy way to calculate this other than to enumerate all possibilities. Is there a simpler solution?

For the second question, my answer was $\frac{6\cdot{4 \choose 1}^7}{52 \choose 7}$, since out of all possible combinations, for any straight, we can choose any of the 4 suited cards, and there are 6 possible straights (beginning with A, 1, 2 ... or 6). However, the answer has $\frac{8\cdot{4 \choose 1}^7}{52 \choose 7}$, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: $A-6$ would be only $6$ cards, but even then I don't see how you count $6$ straights.  To count the straights you must specify if Aces must be High, must be Low, or if they could be either.

Comment: The lowest card could be an 8 with the straight being 8-9-10-J-Q-K-A

Comment: @lulu I meant to say that you could start a straight from cards beginning from A-6.

Comment: @WW1 Thanks, I see. Did not know A could also be high card

Comment: Well, what's wrong with $7,8,9,10,J,Q, K$?

Comment: I think the most common convention would be to allow Aces to be either High or Low but not both simultaneously,  That is, you can't call $J,Q,K, A, 2, 3,4$ a straight.  But conventions vary and  you  should always check what somebody has in mind.

Comment: For the first question, think of using stars and bars to first find number of solutions to $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 37$ where they are positive integers ($\gt 0$).

Answer (score 1):

For 1) because 37 is less than 50 , we can just use stars and bars.

The number of sequences of $k$ natural numbers that sum to $n$ is given by

$$N = \binom{n-1}{k-1}$$

so $$P = \frac{\binom{36}{2}}{50^3}$$

Comment: Oh, right.  I just plugged it into the general method without thinking about it first.

Answer (score 0):

As to the first part, you can do it with generating functions.  The number of ways to get a sum of $37$ is the coefficient of $x^{37}$ in $$(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^{50})^3=\left(\frac{x-x^{51}}{1-x}\right)^3=x^3(1-x^{50})^3(1-x)^{-3}$$  Now, since we are only interested in the coefficient of $x^{37}$ we can ignore the middle term in the last expression, and we see that the answer is the coefficient of $x^{34}$ in the power series for $(1-x)^{-3}$, or $$\frac{(-3)(-4)\cdots(-36)}{34!}=\frac{36!}{2!34!}=\frac{36\cdot35}2=\boxed{630}$$